# input string was not in a correct format date time c#

Tags: c#, date

I am  getting a date time from a URL as string and convert it to Date Time format

I get this exception

> Input string was not in correct format

And this is my code that i tried

```
string time = expiredorno;
var result = Convert.ToDateTime(time);
string timeleft = result.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Note: in the code The variable 'expiredorno' have this value "2021/05/03 14:54:14 PM"

Comment: We need to see the value of the time string, because the problem is with that.

Comment: @Cleptus, It wasn't when I added that comment.

Comment: You could try to parse the string with [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 1):

The input string format is likely invalid under the default culture settings. You could set the culture for the convert method as specified here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToDateTime_System_String_

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Convert.ToDateTime(time, culture);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string time = "2021/05/03 14:54:14 PM";
var result = Convert.ToDateTime(time, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string timeleft = result.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

We can try adding CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.
We can use one of the proper parse methods from the DateTime Struct (System) | Microsoft Docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.7.2